# Jquery only hiding last notice

Tags: javascript, jquery, notice

I made a notice system for my dashboard with javascript/jquery however when I insert 3 notices at the same time it will only hide the last inserted notice.

```
function NewNotice(title, message, bool){
                if(bool){
                    var color = "green";
                    var icon = "checkmark";
                } else {
                    var color = "red";
                    var icon = "cancel-2";
                }
                $('.notices').append('<div class="bg-color-'+ color +'">');
                $n = $('.notices').children().last();
                $n.append('<a href="#" class="close">');
                $n.append('<div class="notice-icon"> <i class="icon-'+ icon +' fg-color-white" style="font-size:32px;"></i> </div>');
                $n.append('<div class="notice-image"> <i class="icon-'+ title +' fg-color-white" style="font-size:48px;"></i> </div>');
                $n.append('<div class="notice-header fg-color-white">'+ title +'</div>');
                $n.append('<div class="notice-text">Message: "'+ message +'" was posted.</div>');

                $n.animate({right:'+=380'}, 500);
                var t = setTimeout(function(){
                   $n.animate({
                       right:'-=380'
                   }, 500, function(){
                       $n.hide();
                   });
                },5000);
            }
```

I would guess that it will only hide the last because I'm caching the selector but I don't know how to work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the `$n` variable without declaring it the function, so it's getting auto-created at the global scope, which means that in your `setTimeout` function the $n is referring to the global variable which will be set by the most recent time that `NewNotice` is run.

To fix it, just add `var` to when you're creating your variables.

```
var $n2 = $(this);
var $n = $('.notices').children().last();
```

Comment: The $n2 is actually useless, I'll remove it. I will try this asap!